# ROS Namespace related confusion

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developing a ROS Package on ROS Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS.

The package contains a launch file with the following content:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="host" default="172.17.69.137"/>
  <arg name="port" default="1357"/>
  <arg name="timeout" default="1000"/>

  <arg name="model" default="$(find my_package)/files/robot.urdf"/>
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(arg model)"/>
  <param name="use_gui" value="true"/>
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"/>

  <node name="receiver" pkg="my_package" type="receiver" output="screen">
    <param name="host" value="$(arg host)" />
    <param name="port" value="$(arg port)" />
    <param name="timeout" value="$(arg timeout)" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

The CPP source file uses the above parameters as shown below:

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "receive_potentio", ros::init_options::AnonymousName);

ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::Publisher jointStatePub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::JointState>("joint_states", 1);

std::string host;
int timeout, port;

// the following doesn't work. However when relative is
// used, i.e. ros::NodeHandle nh("~") it works!
nh.getParam("host", host);
nh.getParam("port", port);
nh.getParam("timeout", timeout);
```

The absolute namespace defined in this way i.e., `ros::NodeHandle nh` doesn't get params `nh.getParam("host", host)` . But when relative  is used `ros::NodeHandle nh("~")`, param `nh.getParam("host", host)` works. However in this case `ros::Publisher jointStatePub` doesn't work!

I think I am missing something obvious here. How do I make both of the work together?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318014/ros-namespace-related-confusion/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2019-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-08**:\

> However in this case `ros::Publisher jointStatePub` doesn't work!

How does a `Publisher` "not work" exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> <node name="receiver" pkg="my_package" type="receiver" output="screen">
> ```

```
  <param name="host" value="$(arg host)" />
  <param name="port" value="$(arg port)" />
  <param name="timeout" value="$(arg timeout)" />
</node>
```

Here, you're setting `host`, `port` and `timeout` as *private parameters* of the `receiver` node.

But here:

> ```
> ros::NodeHandle nh;
> ```

```
[..]
nh.getParam("host", host);
nh.getParam("port", port);
nh.getParam("timeout", timeout);
```

You're trying to access those parameters as if they're "public" (ie: exist in some other namespace than the node's namespace).

That won't work.

> ```
> // the following doesn't work. However when relative is
> ```

```
// used, i.e. ros::NodeHandle nh("~") it works!
```

And that makes sense, as `~` has a special meaning as a namespace name (which is what the first argument in that particular `ros::NodeHandle` ctor is): it refers to the *private namespace* of the node in which the `NodeHandle` is created.

So now you're reading private parameters from the private namespace. And that succeeds.

See also [wiki/Parameter Server](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4